# Concurrence of four Newton lines

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, let line $L$ be a line in the plane, $L_N$ = Newton line of $(BC, CA, AB, L)$. Show that the Newton lines of $(L, L_N, AB, AC)$ ; $(L, L_N, BC, BA)$; $(L, L_N, CA, CB)$ and $L_N$ are concurrent.  The result is well-known?

Comment: This has been unanswered for over 2 years.  Perhaps the result is not well known.  Have you been able to find a proof?